# What happened to Olaf in the 1931 earthquake?

Tags: the-almighty-johnsons

Olaf Johnson (Baldr) says that he is 92 years old, so born around 1919.  We learn that the [Napier/Hastings earthquake of 1931](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1931_Hawke%27s_Bay_earthquake) was the result of earlier incarnations of the gods failing to find Frigg before Odin died, and it killed them all.  Gods come into their power at the age of 21 (so around 1940 for Olaf).

How do these times fit together?  Olaf was alive (and so presumably a reincarnated god) in 1931, but not among those killed by the earthquake.

Did he survive somehow? (Because he hadn't come into his power yet, maybe?) Was there another Baldr in '31, and he transferred into Olaf later somehow? Was Baldr not one of the reincarnated gods that died in '31?

Answer (score 1):

To date there hasn't been a reference that I remember as to all the gods being killed.  Rather it was all those in that area.  This was referenced again in an early episode by the goddesses discussing killing Odin, and how far away they would need to be to survive the cataclysm and if they could.

This being the case, Olaf was not necessarily in the Napier/Hastings area when Odin was killed and hence survived the earthquake.

Answer (score 0):

He must have survived because he had not come into his power yet. There is no other reasonable explanation. However it does not explain how he knew about his godness, if all the other gods died when he was 12. I suspect that this is one of those plot holes that can be covered by "Olaf won't talk about it". there may have been more to it, but I suspect we will never know.

Answer (score 0):

The Odin who died in 1931 was not related (in the human sense) to Olaf. The rule is that the human, blood relatives of an Odin who dies with his Frigg-quest unfulfilled die along with him - along with however many mortals die in the associated calamity, of course.

Comment: That's not necessarily the rule, after all the goddesses were scared of dying if they killed Odin after Axl's 21st birthday.